# Can't edit credentials Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I open the file this way:

```
EDITOR="atom --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

I get a brand new file that is assigned a new name (a number.credentials.yml) and reports "New credentials encrypted and saved," and I am not given the opportunity to edit the file. 
Then I type:

```
bin/rails credentials:show
```

and I get the default aws: 123 etc....
 So I delete both the credentials.yml.enc and the master key and start over, with the same results. the new credentials.yml.enc is created with the default verbage, but I cannot edit it.
I am using ruby 2.5.3 and rails 5.2.2. Ubuntu 18.04 if that matters. I have followed all the recommendations given elsewhere on this exact topic, but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 10):

With `rails credentials:show`, you cannot edit your `credentials.yml`. You have to use `EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit` to edit your `credentails.yml`.

Delete your `master.key` than you need to run the command `EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit` which it won't find the `master.key` and creates new one with `crendetials.yml.enc`. After that, add some stuffs and close that file with `CTRL + W`. Now you can see the result with `rails credentials:show`.

Comment: Yes I'm aware the :show is not how to edit. Please read my entire post. I used the :show to demonstrate that the :edit was not opening the credentials.yml.enc file but was opening a brand new file then closing it right away. I deleted the master key and the .enc file and went through the same process with the same result several times. It might well have something to do with the editor I'm using...

Comment: OK I just confirmed that the editor atom may be the issue. I used EDITOR=vi ...etc  and all is well. Maybe I don't have atom configured correctly. Inasmuch as a) I don't imagine I will be editing that file too often and b. I struggle using vim, I'm OK for the moment. Thanks everyone who looked.

Comment: Well, I use Atom editor to edit my credentials without any problem; however, I'm happy that you solved the problem with Vim

Comment: I won't stop using Atom. I like it a lot since I found out how to keep from moving files into folders accidentally. Maybe my problem is a combination of Ubuntu and Atom? Thanks, Berkhan.

Comment: It can't be since I use Ubuntu 18.04 and Atom 1.34.0 :)

Comment: Try nano instead of vi if its present on your system- its good enough for simple text editing and a lot less cryptic than vi/emacs.

Comment: Interesting. I just tried it again and paid closer attention. Even though I am in the proper directory, atom creates and saves a "credentials.yml" file in the root tmp folder. I tried nano, as max suggested, and it works as expected (and without the --wait flag). So I'm guessing it's in my atom settings somewhere. I changed the default path to my project path, but that wasn't it.

Comment: I have the same issue with Textmate. After uncommenting the default `aws` values, saving and quitting the Textmate editor, I got the message `New credentials encrypted and saved.`. When checking with: `rails credentials:show`, it still displays the old commented values and raises the error when trying to access to `Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id]`, - `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`. Using Rails `5.2.3` on a fresh app.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the exact same issue. It appears the issue is the quotes surrounding the specified text editor. (Note: I am running MacOS, not Ubuntu):

**Doesn't work as intended**

```
EDITOR=“vim” rails credentials:edit
```

> New credentials encrypted and saved.

But I didn't want to create new credentials. I wanted to edit my existing **credentials.yml.enc** file.

**Works as intended**

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

This does what I expect: opens up the credentials.yml.enc file in vim in an unencrypted format.

Answer (score 1):

You need install vim for ubuntu, use this commmand:

**sudo apt-get install vim**

I had the same problem and solutioned with that. ;)

Comment: Same thing for `nano`. Because it wasn't installed, Rails would show the "New credentials encrypted and saved." message. Once I installed the editor, I was able to edit the existing creds.